# Centered icons above / over / on top of text in Navbar? (Bootstrap 3)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, icons, navbar, nav

I spent some time searching for a way to do this & tried a couple (close) examples without success.

**[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jayinthebay/gv7gouda/)**

I'm basically trying to put the little android icons centered above the "Sub#" text in the subnav. Any help would be appreciated. The area of the code is:

```
         <span class="">
         <span>Sub1</span>
         <i class="fa fa-android fa-lg"></i>
         </span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap each of icons in `col-xs-2` with a `col-xs-offset-1` in the first `div` to make it centered.  You can use `<br>` tags to create a line break between your icon and your text.

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gv7gouda/1/)

```
<div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2">
    <i class="fa fa-android fa-lg"></i><br>
    Sub1
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <i class="fa fa-android fa-lg"></i><br>
    Sub2
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <i class="fa fa-android fa-lg"></i><br>
    Sub3
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <i class="fa fa-android fa-lg"></i><br>
    Sub4
</div>
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <i class="fa fa-android fa-lg"></i><br>
    Sub5
</div>
```

In your original code you have a bunch of extra `<span>`s I am not sure what purpose those are serving.  I removed those.

Comment: This looks like an option, but how does this work if I have 7 subnav menu items?

Comment: Change `col-xs-2` to `col-xs-1`, it's a bit of a tight squeeze but it fits.  With 7 columns you won't be able to center it perfectly, your `col-xs-offset` will become either `col-xs-offset-2` or `col-xs-offset-3`.  Centering it properly will require additional CSS.

Comment: If I have an even # of menu items (e.g. 6, 8) then I see how I can adjust offset accordingly. But this presents a different issue perhaps with longer text on the menu... http://jsfiddle.net/jayinthebay/gv7gouda/4/   I guess I'm not trying to give a fixed amount of space for each menu item, but rather give each the space it needs and centering the entire menu block.

Comment: Yeah you'll run into some issues there, but I don't think it's worth trying to figure out a fix.  If this is for a mobile phone the UX will suffer if you have 8 menu items across.  Look at some mobile apps and/or responsive sites that are well designed, you won't find anything like that on them.

Comment: This is as closest to a solution as I think I'll come for now. In mobile, I would actually use hidden-xs / visible-xs to swap out the text menu for icons only. Still debating. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Something along those lines?

```
<span>Sub1</span>
  <span style='position:absolute;left:50%'>
    <span style='border:1px solid red;margin-left:-100%;'>
      <i class="fa fa-android fa-lg"></i>
    </span>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: This seems like a poor way to go, having all of those nested inline styles will create headaches for you if you ever edit the page.

Comment: This didn't work. Maybe show it in jsfiddle if it worked for you. I have 7 menu items at present I'd like to show.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood what you wanted to do, thought you wanted the icon on top of the text for some reason. The solution above works fine for what you're after!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was a simple br tag after the icon and "text-align: center" on "ul li a".
Html:

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><br>Home page</a></li>
```

CSS:

```
ul li a {
    text-align: center;
}
```