# Bootstrap 3 Navbar with icons and centered text under

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to find an example on bootstrap 3 of a navbar with icons and text centered under it like this image:

[image]

Any ideas on where I could find an example of something like this in bootstrap 3?

Comment: Search Google. You should be able to find examples like this: http://codeply.com/go/IJmkMrzRxA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to these two posts on Stackoverflow:
[Centered icons above / over / on top of text in Navbar? (Bootstrap 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25330153/centered-icons-above-over-on-top-of-text-in-navbar-bootstrap-3)

or

[Centering navbar icon text - Rails app using Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31040298/centering-navbar-icon-text-rails-app-using-bootstrap)